# How can I make a "Movie Clip" node start at a certain frame of the scene?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, keyframes

When I use "Movie Clip" node in Blender 2.7, it always starts at Scene Frame 1. How can I change it in order to make it start at Frame 6, for instance? The movie clip I am using is a Movie FX for another video, and I want to use it with the Mix node.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace the "movie clip" node for an "Input Image" node and use **Movie** as source.

**Frames** will give you control on the source's duration (in frames): How many frames do you want to use?

**Start Frame** is the frame in the scene at which the video clip will start playing.

**Offset** allows you to select the first frame of the video source.

[image]

**Cyclic** Will make the cycle of frames start over, if the number of frames is different that those on the scene or if you are using any offset. If you want to hold a frame, before or after the specified number of frames or freeze a frame you would need to disable this box.

**Auto Refresh** if disabled you will not see the sequence of images change.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear  write up @cegaton. I am going to re-post a version of this on my blog. The more people who understand it the better.

Comment: So in case someone was wondering, you can't use this to change the frame start of a "Movie Clip". You will have to export the movie clip as an image sequence or movie file; then, use the Image input node instead.

Comment: @Azmisov you can use the image sequence node and load a video file. No need to export as image sequence. As long as you set the image sequence node to movie mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems with the image node, you can change the offset of a Movie Clip in the MCE (Movie Clip Editor), also known as the Tracker. Go to the movie clip's properties and change the start frame and offset there. Remember though, you can only have one instance of that movie clip per scene, so you can only change the offset once.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to replicate a VSE edit in the node editor then you can adjust the :

**length**, **frame start** and **offset**

Here is a node mimicking a VSE edit:

- *VSE* Length = *Node* Frames (duration in frames eg.73)
- *VSE* Start Frame = *Node* Start Frame (Position on timeline + Offset eg. 73+(526), note that this could have a negative number for start value when the strip begins before zero on the timeline)
- *VSE* Trim Duration "START" = *Node* Offset (Trimmed clip start eg. 526)

[image: Match an Image node to VSE strip]

- Don't forget to add a Distort > Scale or Transform node after the image/movie node to match the VSE autoscale function.