# How can I delete a single frame?

Tags: animation, import, keyframes

I have an extra frame that's not supposed to be in the video that I imported in. I'm not sure why it's there, but for the video to play smoothly, I need frame 116 gone and for frame 117 to become frame 116 essentially. Thank in advance!

Ethan

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-can-i-make-a-movie-clip-node-start-at-a-certain-frame-of-the-scene/9123#9123

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a "hard cut" (SH-K) after frame 115, shift the right strip that's now separated a little (to the right), hard cut it's 1st frame off (frame 116), and drag what's left to the left again to join it with the left strip.  The two strips will play and render in sequence, and importantly, without frame 116.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. You could add your video 2 times and let the one video sequenz end at frame 115 and let the other start at frame 117.

Also you could render your video as a png sequenz, load it into blender as image sequenz and leave frame 116 unimported.