# Image sequence customizing

Tags: image

I'm trying to do some scenes which use a mixture of 3D backgrounds with 2D animated characters.The best way I've figured this out so far is to use a plane with an image sequence of pngs which hold the frames.

The problem with this method is Blender seams to only load image sequences based on image numbering. If I wanted to do a sequence which loops say, frames 0-5, then repeats 4-0 for the 'return' of the animation, I would have to load frames doubled up.

Is there a way, maybe with a script, to change the sequence order? I can see it as a useful plugin but my python skills are pretty much non existent.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to do what you want, just learn how to use the **Frames**, Start Frame**, **Offset** and Cyclic controls on the Image Sequence node used as the texture of the plane's material.

[image]

Read: [Same Video on each face, but with different time delay?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay/61339#61339)

Then to change to another sequence of repetitions use a mix color node to start the next iteration and animate the **Mix Factor**

[image]

Read: [How do you animate image texture materials in blender cycles with keyframes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793)

Comment: Ah, I knew about the offset stuff but.. never really gotten into the nodes much.. thanks, i'll look into that node but for changing the sequence