# How can I control playback of video textures?

Tags: texturing, video

I’m working on a video in which photographs inside picture frames come to life but I do not know how to control the playback of the video textures.

I already have the video texture loaded in the picture frame. Right now it plays immediately when I start playback in Blender.

Here’s what I want to do.

I have the camera animated to approach the photo.  Until the camera reaches it, the video texture is “paused” on the first frame.

When the camera focuses on the photo, I want the video texture to play.

Finally, I want to pause the video on the last frame.

The camera then moves over to another picture frame and the process repeats.

What is the best way to do this in Blender.

Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163661/image-sequence-customizing/163692#163692

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay/61339#61339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the object with the material. Go to the Properties window, click the Material Properties tab, and extend the Base Color settings by clicking the little triangle. Now you can see a field for the Start Frame value.

Alternatively select the material in the Shader Editor window and change the Start Frame value in the Image Texture node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize it was that easy!