# Play multiple videos in EEVEE starting at different time

Tags: eevee-render-engine, video

I have to planes with different video files in each one. I want to play the videos in EEVEE in both planes but starting a different time.

[image]

Now, with "play animation" both videos start at same time, how can play them independently under EEVEE?.

Comment: Read: [Same video on each face but with different time delay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: and [image sequence customizing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163661/image-sequence-customizing/163692#163692)

Comment: Also worth reading https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "Offset" in the image input. To have one show black before starting, use the Mix RGB node with black as one of the inputs, and animate the factor to change from 1 to 0 (or vice versa) right when the video starts.