# Second Instance of Video Texture Is Playing Even Though Start Frame Not Reached

Tags: texturing, video

I've researched about `Frames`, `Start Frame`, `Offset` and based on my research `Frames` is the total amount of frames in the video or any frames lesser than video, `Start Frame` is the frame in the main timeline where the video texture should start playing and i've set it to 700. That means when i render frame 615, the picture displayed in the face with the video texture should be at frame 1 but apparently that isn't the case for me. So my question is, is it a known bug or did i misunderstand these fields? By the way, my first instance of the video texture worked but the second instance is not working.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

i finally got it working after clicking this icon in red box:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using 2 instances of the same Video texture on different frames in the scene timeline make sure to click the button in red box to make single-user copy

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check *Auto Refresh* to get video updated every time then you change frame:

[image]

Comment: but in here it says "start frame" is for the scenes timeline: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163661/image-sequence-customizing and it did work for me for one video texture but this time not working for my 2nd video texture. and offset also doesn't work in my case... maybe my blender version is messed up

Comment: Probably it's better to look at official documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/image/image_settings.html#movie

Comment: yes that's the doc i saw too. but something wrong with my blender damn, it always shows the same frame sequence when i press F12 no matter what values i input :(

Comment: Of course, if you have 180 frames video, and you want to start playing from 700th frame of 180, it is negative number frames for playing...

Comment: no. my entire main scene timeline is 800 frames. and the video texture is 180 frames. i want that video texture to start playing when i'm on frame 700 of the main scene timeline. and no matter what values i use, whether i use `offset` or the `start frame`, nothing works. so that obviously is a bug?

Comment: Hm, maybe check auto refresh, to get video updated on a frame change

Comment: i finally found the source of the problem! i put an update in my post, i had to click that little icon beside the video name that says "2" to make it a single user copy. that's quite confusing, i had suspicion that the values in Frames, Start Frame, Offset for the 1st usage were interfering with the 2nd usage, but that should have meant that a change in those values should have reflected in the first usage but it maintained different values making me think that they don't interfere. anyway resolved finally!