# Same image sequence one offset but not the other

Tags: materials, node-editor, image, eevee-render-engine

- plane A assigned material A that has an image sequence.
- plane B assigned material B with the same image sequence.

When i change the frames offset of the image sequence in material B both are changed

How to offset only one without effecting the other?

Comment: Related:  [Same Video on each face, but with different time delay?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that materials is different. If it is not true, you will see a number near material name:

[image]

In this case press on digit to make independent copy

Next step - image node. Click on digit here:

[image]

Also mesh data can be linked:

[image]

So do you understand the rule? Remove all digits to make independent copy of material, image, mesh data.

Comment: Thanks that did work