# animate the material node (image)

Tags: materials

I wonder if there's any possibility to animate frame "17" as picture show to frame "19".
I just need to key those frames that I need.
Any help would be grateful.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-can-i-make-a-movie-clip-node-start-at-a-certain-frame-of-the-scene/9123#9123

Comment: You can use an image node to load video.

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay/61339#61339

Comment: ...I don't understand well the question: what does " animate frame "17" as picture show to frame "19"." mean? And how the bottom image node relates to the upper ones?