# Can I reuse a plane with an image sequence

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image

I have a plane with an image sequence on it, which works fine on itself.

During my animation, I'd like to play that image sequence at multiple completely different frames, so I was wondering if there was any other way than duplicating the plane?

Comment: Use "cyclic" on the image source node. Read:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-can-i-make-a-movie-clip-node-start-at-a-certain-frame-of-the-scene/9123#9123

Comment: but I don't want them do be directly following each other, edited to make this clear

Comment: Same thing, you can animate the values for start, frame or offset to specify what frames play and when.

Comment: no I can't, these values are, except for the offset, not keyframeable

Comment: Animating the offset should work.  Make sure your interpolation mode is set to constant in your graph editor and then keyframe the offset right before you want the image sequence to repeat.