# How can I "slideshow" between image textures on a plane?

Tags: animation, texturing, image

I have something like a slideshow I'm working on (essentially a shadow box that flips through images), and I can't find an easy way to change the image on a plane.

The two solutions I can think of are:

1. Copy paste the image plane for every image, create a new material for every image, and show/hide each plane throughout the animation.  Seems like a lot of redundancy.
2. Copy paste the image shader for ever image and create a vast network of mix shaders to move from one to the next.  This seems also like a lot of redundancy and huge ugly node graph.

What I wish I could do is change the image chosen for my Image Texture as a keyframe, but unfortunately insert keyframe does not work for the image path option.

So how can I do this?  Is there any way to do it that doesn't include a ton of redundancy?

Image for clarity:
[image]

Comment: The easiest way would be to name the sequence of images with the same prefix and have a consecutive number at the end, so that they behave like an image sequence. Then use the image sequence as part of the material. Read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36793/1853 and   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-can-i-make-a-movie-clip-node-start-at-a-certain-frame-of-the-scene/9123#9123 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay/61339#61339

Answer (score 3):

You name all the images you want as a sequence, for example: image0001.png, image0002.png and so on. You can do this by importing them in Blender VSE and exporting all of them as pngs or you can do this using imagemagick.

[image]
[image]

Then in the shader, you import the first image.

[image]

You change the value from single image to image sequence and set the number of frames to your total number of images.

[image]

Now the image sequencer will play all the frames from frame 1 automatically. If you want total control, set the start frame so that the last image of the sequence is the first image in the sequencer.

[image]

Now you can keyframe the offset value and change it however you want. You can hold on a frame or let it run as a sequence.

Comment: Please add images directly into your post, not as external links. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I can't add more than 5 images as my account is new.

Comment: Add in as many as you can, put a link to the rest and I'll add them in.

Comment: Nice Answer :)  This part is not very clear, can you please edit a little, Thanks