# Video clip on plane EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm french (sorry for my poor english), i'm a new on blender 2.8 and older...

So, I have a question about planes nd video clip.

I put a video on a plane. I gave the frames information but I can't see the movement on the render movie.

Someone can explain me I can I do?

Thanks,
Fred

[image]

Comment: related: [How can I make a “Movie Clip” node start at a certain frame of the scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-can-i-make-a-movie-clip-node-start-at-a-certain-frame-of-the-scene/9123#9123) or [Movie Clip On Plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane/39885#39885)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine here. (current build, 2.80.2)
Check your "Image Texture" Settings:
Frames: 1000
Start Frame: 3000
Maybe this is confuning blender. ;)

Comment: Thank you. Yes you have right for this detail but, I modified my settings after and I can't render with the video film, just one fixed picture..

Comment: Note that Eevee (and tblender 2.8) is still work in progress, nowhere near finished. Some things are missing, broken, or buggy. Save yourself headaches and use the current stable version, specially if you are learning how to use the software.

Comment: Cegaton, thanks. The only way for me, with EEVEE, is to genarate frame per frame!

Comment: Also: The movie is not updating if you play the timeline. In final render it will, but in preview you have to scrub thru the timeline by mouse or keyboard.