# How to make plane tracked video start compositing from a certain frame?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Thanks to your help, I can now plane track a video and nicely add a video on top of the plane.
However, I have a problem..

So, I only need to track a small part of a large video. I set the range to "Start: 1910, End: 2374" so I could only track the plane for those few hundred frames. And it works!

However, when I use the nodes to add the video in, the video starts playing, on the plane, from frame 0, effectively ending before it even reaches 200 frames.

How can I make it so that the superimposed video starts playing at the frame range I tracked the plane in (starting at frame 1910)? And also, is it possible to loop the video? If so, how?

Here are the nodes I used:

[image: node]

Answer (score 0):

I found it out:

I fixed it by looking at this post ([How can I make a "Movie Clip" node start at a certain frame of the scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-can-i-make-a-movie-clip-node-start-at-a-certain-frame-of-the-scene?rq=1)). I replaced the "movie clip' nodes for "image" nodes, and put the background video at "Start from 1910, and Offset 1910". Then I offset the composited video to 1910 frames. Voila!

I had to scrub through the timeline to check that it was precisely matched. I rendered a smaller sequence once to check through it, and then returned to the project to "finely" adjust it down to each frame.

Stackexchange is a wonder, really :O